# Activate correct locale upon front-end entry

Tags: entries, localization, frontend

Is there any way, upon creating new entries via front-end form, to ***not*** have all locale versions of those entries active?

I’d like to think I could just set something like
`<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en_us”>`

Comment: Why not just set the locales to be disabled by default under your section's settings?

Comment: That's what I originally did (see answer below). Yet it still doesn't activate the correct locale. Submitting a new entry *did* activate a locale, but not the correct one (a form filled out on `en_us` domain should trigger the `en_us` locale only). Instead it triggered the very first in the list of locales (not sure whether it detected that from locale ID or alphabetical, in my case)

Comment: And using `<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en_us">`  and `<input type="hidden" name="localeEnabled" value="1">` doesn't do it?

Comment: Yes. Yes it does. I wasn't sure `<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en_us">` was even a thing because I couldn't find documentation on it, so I removed it- assuming saving an entry from my locale would trigger the correct one. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en_us”>` works as expected, as long as the section settings for that entry has all the locales set to be disabled by default.

Upon creating a new entry via front-end form, only the specific locale was activated. However, creating the entry in the admin panel, they are all left off by default. (Seems correct, just remind any clients that might be using the admin panel to enable whichever locale).